# Can someone explain regex this regex expression

Tags: java

Hi there I'm new to Java and was going through some information on regex and I couldn't comprehend this the following expression:

"^[a-zA-Z\-]+$"

Could someone be kind enough to explain each and every character in this expression?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 3):

```python
^           $  # Check if the entire string matches,
 [        ]+   # with one or more of the following characters:
  a-z          #  Any lowercase (ASCII) letter
     A-Z       #  Any uppercase (ASCII) letter
        \-     #  Or an "-" (the `\` is used to escape it)
```

Or in short: this regex checks if a given string consists solely of (ASCII) letters and/or `-`, and is non-empty.

[**Try it online.**](https://ideone.com/QRKTnS)

Answer (score 1):

[a-zA-Z] means all characters a through or A through Z, inclusive.
The "\" inside the square bracket is used as an escape character.
Symbol "+" in the end signified that your regex can occur once or more times.

Comment: So what does it mean? And what does `^`, `-` and `$` mean?